# I need to get the alt attribute of the clicked image element. The alt value of multiple images on click. How to do in tag manager JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager

This is the exact code that i'm using currently.

```
function () {
    if (document.querySelector("#wrapper > section.panel.spacer--banner.bg--banner.flex-column.first > div > div > div.col-lg-5 > div > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a > img").onclick = true) {
        return "playstore";
    }
    else if (document.querySelector("#wrapper > section.panel.spacer--banner.bg--banner.flex-column.first > div > div > div.col-lg-5 > div > ul > li.d-none.d-xl-block > button").onclick = true) {
        return "appstore";
    }
    else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

I need to get the image alt attribute of any clicked element in a web page (via tag manager). In tag manager, I'm tracking events. For the events, I need to pass the parameter as image alt value. Can someone help with the exact js code?

Comment: Your code is not doing what you think it does. You are overwriting the `onclick` of a Element by re-assigning it to `true`. (`document.querySelector(...).onclick = true`). You should instead *add* a `click` event listener (using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)) to that element.

Comment: also, the second `querySelector` in your code is targeting a `button`, for which you seem to want to return `appstore` - that can't be the `alt` attribute, where does it come from?

Comment: Who/which service does consume the provided function? In addition the provided selector hell does not quite match the requirement of ... _"I need to get the image alt attribute of **any** clicked **element**"_.

Comment: Furthermore, why does one provide a totally generic name like **wrapper** as an element's `id` value? And why in the entire structure does one not place specific `id`'s or even some more meaningful class names exactly at the areas of interest? (In opposite to `#wrapper` and it's queries of hell).